# Monitoring DB used connections and http threads via zabbix

Tags: java, glassfish, jmx, zabbix

I'm trying to adjust zabbix monitoring for my application on glassfish. But can't find if it is possible to adjust monitoring of used DB connections from glassfish connection pools and http threads. Was thinking of monitoring via JMX items but cant find any ways to boot AMX. So i'm here to ask if there is any way of booting AMX for MBeans or other ways to get used DB connections and http threads.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you already can collect jmx information with zabbix and known how to create a jmx item to monitor.

For number of current connections

```
jmx["com.sun.appserv:name=NAME_OF_THE_APPLICATION,type=jdbc-connection-pool,category=monitor,server=server",NumConnUsed-current]
```

For number of destroyed connections

```
jmx["com.sun.appserv:name=NAME_OF_THE_APPLICATION,type=jdbc-connection-pool,category=monitor,server=server",NumConnDestroyed-count]
```

Number of creations connections

```
jmx["com.sun.appserv:name=NAME_OF_THE_APPLICATION,type=jdbc-connection-pool,category=monitor,server=server",NumConnCreated-count]
```

Number of available connections

```
jmx["com.sun.appserv:name=NAME_OF_THE_APPLICATION,type=jdbc-connection-pool,category=monitor,server=server",NumConnFree-current]
```

These are examples, the best way to find what you want to monitor with jmx is using jconsole.